# How to pass a parameter to relational query in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a MANY_MANY relation:

```
'rel'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'MyClass','table(id_1,id_2)',  
             'condition'=>'some condiotions AND field_name=:param')
```

I get the result -instances of Myclass in the siteController:

```
$obj->rel
```

Is it possible (and how) to pass the :param from the controller to the relation's query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's not possible, but what you want to do can be achieved in a different way. 
Check the following from [the Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#dynamic-relational-query-options):

> We can use dynamic relational query options in both with() and the with option. The dynamic options will overwrite existing options as specified in the relations() method. ...

So your query could be something like this (if we want to use eager loading approach):

```
$param='something';
$obj=SomeModel::model()->with(array(
'rel'=>array('condition'=>'some conditions AND field_name=:param',
             'params' => array(':param' => $param))
))->findAll();
// some more code
$obj->rel->attributeOne;
```

Or when using the lazy loading approach to perform relational query:

```
$param='something';
$obj=SomeModel::model()->findByPk(1);
$rels=$obj->rel(array('condition'=>'some conditions AND field_name=:param',
                      'params' => array(':param' => $param)
));
```

Hope this helps. Do read the linked guide. Ask for clarifications, if needed.

Edit:
As already mentioned in the comments below, `some conditions` can be put in the model's relation, and only additional conditions need to be specified while querying. The additional condition is automatically `AND` 'ed to the model's relation condition. This seems contrary to the documentation. Anyway the following code can be used:

```
// In the model's relation:
'rel'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'MyClass','table(id_1,id_2)',  
         'condition'=>'some conditions');
```

Controller:

```
$param='something';
$obj=SomeModel::model()->with(array(
'rel'=>array('condition'=>'field_name=:param',
             'params' => array(':param' => $param))
))->findAll();
```

Also see [this comment](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#c1039) in the linked documentation

Comment: I though about that and it seems to me a nice way to solve the problem. On other hand I'll always have to repeat the static "some conditions" and it looks ugly(

Comment: ok, at the moment i can't think of a workaround for that, but then there are always trade-offs to consider in programming. ugly vs. whats possible. :)

Comment: my mistake. no override here. the new condition is added in the end of the query

Answer (score 3):

You can try "Parameterized Named Scopes":

```
function relations() {
    return array(
        'rel'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'MyClass','table(id_1,id_2)',  
             'condition'=>'some conditions')
    )
}


public function relByFieldName($fieldValue=5)
{
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'with' => 'rel',
        'condition' => 'field_name = :value',
        'params' => array(':value' => $fieldValue)
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
$models=Model::model()->relByFieldName(100)->findAll();
```